# CSS layout not staying in same position

Tags: html, css

I have a layout for a website i am working on, basically i have about 10 pages but my footer will not stay in the same place.  I have tried so many different variations of code and have been unsuccessful.

The footer should stay at the bottom of the page in the same place on every page.

I am fairly new to this so bear with me if there is any obvious mistakes.

I have created a JSFiddle with a page where the footer is at the bottom but it inst as far down as i need.

```
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  clear:both;
  position:relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mjbL7tcx/

I have created another JSFiddle with another page where it is no where at all where i want it.
http://jsfiddle.net/dej6b2df/

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Footers that are position:relative will be relative to the element before it. Google for dynamic, sticky footer with jQuery or if it's only going to ever be 20px http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: To start your start a tags are not closed.

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ I hope this will help you.

Comment: You have some serious HTML validation errors going on, such as placing divs inside broken link (`a`) tags. Try fixking those first.

Comment: and just my personal opinion, sticky footer really don't achieve much aesthetically, I like my webpage just flow down relatively regardless of length.

Comment: Also you have a div tag that hasn't been closed in your first fiddle.

 <!--end of aboutContent div-->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your HTML code on both your example pages (too long to post as code chunk and unnecessary):

[Page 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/bg8smkpw/)

[Page 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/n4h0ynwe/)

The solution is on the CSS side of things: don't float your photo elements, you should be good to go. I also optimized your css styles for your photo-divs since you can set a `photo-div` class to all your photo divs, style them as a group, and use their numeric class (ex: `photo-div1`) to set the background image:

```
.photo-div {
    width: 241px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: 90px;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    box-shadow: 0px 7px 7px #999;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}
.photo-div1 {
    background-image: url(images/wildlife/cow.jpg);
}
.photo-div2 {
    background-image: url(images/food/ice-cream.jpg);
}
.photo-div3 {
    background-image: url(images/flowers/blue-bells.jpg);
}
.photo-div4 {
    background-image: url(images/sport/cycling-zoom.jpg);
}
```

Comment: You can also optimize your styles for the image link descriptions inside each photo-div, but I'll let you figure that out by yourself using my example as reference.